# performSelectorOnMainThread throws message deallocated

Tags: iphone, objective-c, synchronization

While parsing of the twitter data, I used threads to call the main URL to download the data. It does the downloading perfectly but when I hit the back button while the data is downloading it throws performSelectorOnMainThread message deallocated. I know we can use isCancelled but its not working for me yet. Does anyone have come across this issue and have resolved it.

```
- (void)LoadTwitterData
{
NSString *urlString =@"http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=tabc&result_type=recent&rpp=2500";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSDictionary *values = [jsonString JSONValue];    

/**** Throws here *****/
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(didFinishLoadingResults:) withObject:values waitUntilDone:NO];

}
```

Comment: Try to `retain` object `values` before preforming selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `LoadTwitterData:` is in a background thread, you need to create an Auto release pool (If you haven't already). Surround your code with-

```
NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];


//your code

[pool drain];
```

Comment: It crashes still after few attempts of going back and forth and waiting for data to load. Does it have to do anything with the number of calls in auto releasing the pool ?

Comment: yeah. But I found out that there is another main thread running to load the image URL. and while it is loading the images it crashes. I did put autorelease pool around that code but still it fails at the same place.

Comment: You don't need an auto release pool for the main thread. Have you tried enabling zombies to see which object is being released?

Answer (score 2):

If you spin off a thread using a selector on `self`, you need to make sure that `self` is retained for the duration of that thread, otherwise (as in your case) `self` can be deallocated and your thread will try to call back into a zombie. The easiest way to do this is to pass `self` to the thread as an argument. If you use `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:` you should do something like this:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(LoadTwitterData) withObject:self];
```

Or if you use `NSThread` you should pass `self` to the `object:` initializer argument.

In fact the safest way to use thread methods is to make the method static like this:

```
+ (void)LoadTwitterData:(id)arg
{
    // ...
    MyController *self = arg;

    // ... do work

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(didFinishLoadingResults:)
                           withObject:values waitUntilDone:NO];

}
```

This way you are unable to access instance variables by accident which avoids various multi-threading issues. Any and all data the thread needs, including the `self` to callback to, should be passed in as 'arg', which can be an array or dictionary or whatever you need. This way you know that everything the thread needs will be retained for the duration of the thread, and because you aren't accessing instance variables through `self`, another thread can't go and change them around underneath you.

Another thing you should do in a thread method is wrap the whole thing with an autorelease pool:

```
- (void)LoadTwitterData
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    @try {
        // ...
    } @finally {
        [pool drain];
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm seriously wondering why somebody downvoted this answer. The accepted answer (as of writing) is not addressing the issue at all. You are sending a message to `self` which has been deallocated because you hit the back button. Therefore you need to retain `self` while the thread runs. This is standard stuff.

Comment: I didnt do it. I know your answer is correct too. But dont know who gave vote down.